# How to design entities to keep up with the depth of JSON objects?

Tags: c#, database-design, relational-database, entity, efcore

To better context see [Rich Authorization Requests for OAuth2](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-rar-23.html)

As u can read here there are some common data field types like `actions`, `locations` etc.

So I have created C# entity for EF as below:

```
public class AuthorizationDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool AlwaysRequireConsent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApiResource> Locations { get; set; }
    public string SpaceDelimitedActions { get; set; }
    public string SpaceDelimitedDataTypes { get; set; }
    public string SpaceDelimitedPrivileges { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AuthorizationDetailsCustomDataField> CustomDataFields { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

There is no problem with these common fields. But I have to handle custom JSON data fields and register them. So I have created class called `AuthorizationDetailsCustomDataField` which is related with one-to-many with `AuthorizationDetails` entity.

It looks as below:

```
public class AuthorizationDetailsCustomDataField
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
}
```

So in JSON, the custom field with `Name`="custom_field" can looks like it:

```
{
   "custom_field":[
      "read",
      "write"
   ]
}
```

But it also can looks like it:

```
{
   "custom_field":{
      "x":1024,
      "y":2048,
      "z":{
         "a":"3096",
         "b":[
            "abc",
            "xyz"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How it looks depends on configuration. But how can I allow any configuration that developer wants? How can I design the database to make possible for developer to specify their own allowed JSON structures?

Comment: Did you consider saving JSON in a varchar column? This can be a good first step to get it to work...

Comment: If you choose to deploy on top of Postgres you will find it has excellent support for storing deeply nested [JSON columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html).

Comment: It's hard to explain what I mean. I don't want to store JSON objects but to store: what some JSON object can contains, what fields and what these fields are: arrays, strings or numbers and what the fields in fields are and so on through with depth of JSON object.

Comment: @Szyszka947: *"I don't want to store JSON objects"* - but **why** not? Would be the most simple solution for your issue.

Comment: Do you want to store an arbitrary structure in the DB, but not actual values? Try storing a JSON object with the same structure as keys, and types as values.  E.g. `{"customField":["string"]}` or `{"customField":{"x":"int","y":"int","z":{"a":"string", "b":["string"]}`

Comment: You want to allow developers to store a custom schema in the database?

Comment: I want to allow developers to store rules of what must be in the JSON object. The @DavidPement solution seems nice, I will test it.

Comment: Yes, the JSON schema stored in database works very well. Thanks you!